# UIActivityViewController sharing app name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am using `UIACtivityViewController` to to create sharing feature in my app. The problem i am facing is that, the i want to get the real application name which user has used to share the things in my app.

There are some default social services which are mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types

But there are also some other services like Slack, Skype, Linkedin which are not there in the built in services. How can i get the name of these app when user has used these services to share an item from my application. I can map Built in activity types to their corresponding names but how i can get the name of other apps which are not built in because in the `completeionHandler` of the sharing service it only gives us the `activityType` not the human readable String for Activity Title.

```
UIActivityViewController * shareViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[activity] applicationActivities:nil];

  shareViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError){

    NSLog(@"Completed : %d", completed);
    NSLog(@"Activity Type : %@", activityType);

  };
```

Any help will be great thanks